# Django query returns the same objects twice

Tags: mysql, django, filter, duplicates

Generic example. When I do a query like this

```
a = MyObject.objects.filter(...)
```

a will contain everything matched by the filter. When i then do:

```
a.filter(...)
```

a will contain only the objects that matched both filters, right? So after the first filter(), I might have 5 elements, and then after the second filter() I might have 2 of those 5 left?

I am getting weird results with one of my queries. The following query:

```
>>> Item.objects.filter(account__in=Account.objects.filter(customer=a), disabled=False)
[<Item: PSN-100396>]
```

This yields one result. Keep in mind that 100396 is the primary key, so there can only be one Item with this idnetifier. Now when I apply an additional filter that should show only those Items that are on a disabled Invoice or no Invoice:

```
>>> Item.objects.filter(account__in=Account.objects.filter(customer=a), disabled=False).filter(Q(iteminv__invoice__disabled=False) | Q(iteminv__isnull=True))
[<Item: PSN-100396>, <Item: PSN-100396>]
```

I get this result with the same object twice... How is this possible? Did i misunderstand something?

Putting it all in one filter() produces the same weird output:

```
>>> Item.objects.filter(Q(account__in=Account.objects.filter(customer=a)), Q(disabled=False), Q(iteminv__invoice__disabled=False) | Q(iteminv__isnull=True))
[<Item: PSN-100396>, <Item: PSN-100396>]
```

Django version 1.6.2

Comment: Did you look at the SQL query? It may be joining somewhere.

Comment: It seems like that is what is going on. And while googling I found that I could sort it out by adding .distinct(), but I don't understand why it produces duplicates. I have been using Django for a while now, and I have never seen this behaviour, even on complex queries

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Due to the joins involved when filtering on many-to-many relations or reverse foreign key relations instances can appear twice in the result set (In this cases Django will mostly applay an `INNER JOIN` which can produce duplicates). Therefore you should use `distinct()` on your queryset. (The joins in the sql query make an `Item` appear in the table for every relation it has with `Account`.)

See also [the examples in the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) for filtering on many to many relations.

EDIT: If you want to play with the SQL/and or examine the generated query, do something like `print Item.objects.filter(your_query).query`.